# Parsing JSON Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I have this output after json decode.

```
Array
      (
         [CJ] => stdClass Object
            (
              [CID] => 1234 
              [TYPE] => type2222
              [CURRENCY] => GBP
              [OID] => 100000037
              [DISCOUNT] => 0.00
                [PRODUCTLIST] => Array
                  (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                       (
                        [ITEM] => TEST_PRO_02-White-M
                        [QTY] => 2
                        [AMT] => 80.00
                        [DCNT] => 0.00
                       )

                  [1] => stdClass Object
                       (
                        [ITEM] => TEST_PRO_02-White-M
                        [QTY] => 2
                        [AMT] => 0.00
                        [DCNT] => 0.00
                      )

                   [2] => stdClass Object
                      (
                        [ITEM] => TEST_PRO_01-Pink
                        [QTY] => 1
                        [AMT] => 135.00
                        [DCNT] => 0.00
                      )

                   [3] => stdClass Object
                      (
                        [ITEM] => TEST_PRO_01-Pink
                        [QTY] => 1
                        [AMT] => 0.00
                        [DCNT] => 0.00
                      )

               )

         )

   )
```

I need to make a string to put values in iframe. it gives me no result 
but if i put quotes on json string it gives me required result.

```
$x=0;
foreach ($obj->CJ->PRODUCTLIST as $productlist){


 $item=$productlist->ITEM;
 $amount=$productlist->AMT;
 $qty=$productlist->QTY;
 $cj_string.="ITEM".$x."=$item&AMT".$x."=$amount&QTY".$x."=$qty&";
$x++;}
```

it gives me php nonobject parsing error. How do I get values from PRODUCTLIST in the form of

```
item1=value&QTY1=value&AMT1=value&item2=value&QTY2=value&AMT2=value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your question would be this,

```
$cjhelper = '{"CJ":{"CID":"1234","TYPE":"type2222","CURRENCY":"GBP","OID":"100000045","DISCOUNT":"0.00","PRODUCTLIST":[{"ITEM":"TEST_PRO_01-Pink","QTY":"1","AMT":"135.00","DCNT":"0.00"},{"ITEM":"TEST_PRO_01-Pink","QTY":"1","AMT":"0.00","DCNT":"0.00"}]}}';
$obj = json_decode($cjhelper);

$x=1;
$cj_string = "";
  foreach ($obj->CJ->PRODUCTLIST as $productlist){
     $item=$productlist->ITEM;
     $amount=$productlist->AMT;
     $qty=$productlist->QTY;
      if($x!=1) $cj_string.= "&";
     $cj_string.="ITEM".$x."=$item&AMT".$x."=$amount&QTY".$x."=$qty";
    $x++;
    }

echo $cj_string;
```

Your expected output will be

```
ITEM1=TEST_PRO_01-Pink&AMT1=135.00&QTY1=1&ITEM2=TEST_PRO_01-Pink&AMT2=0.00&QTY2=1
```

Comment: can you post the json string here

Comment: cj-helper{"CJ":{"CID":"1234","TYPE":"type2222","CURRENCY":"GBP","OID":"100000045","DISCOUNT":"0.00","PRODUCTLIST":[{"ITEM":"TEST_PRO_01-Pink","QTY":"1","AMT":"135.00","DCNT":"0.00"},{"ITEM":"TEST_PRO_01-Pink","QTY":"1","AMT":"0.00","DCNT":"0.00"}]}}

Comment: When I write your code as it is,  it gives me required result. so basically my json string is missing single quotes. problem in json encoding?

Comment: Where did i went wrong JSON string was made by JSON encoding with dynamic populated values. how i put these singlw quotes